# How to create wiremock extension with encrypt and decrypt text

Tags: python, json, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I want to create decrypt or encrypt function from python and it can call in wiremock function.

For example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjHpP.png

From above picture , I expect Wiremock that can decrypt data (I already have decrypt code from Python) and check my condition. After that it will get JSON result (No encrypt data) and Wiremock have to able to encrypt JSON result (It can't I will send encrypt data directly lol )

so May anyone suggest how to create wiremock extension like this from Python?

I find the solution just write from Java...

Thanks m (_ _) m

Comment: So, you'll have a request to WireMock, WireMock finds the response to send, and encrypts the data before sending the JSON response? And you'd like it to be in Python?

Comment: a mostly like that but I mean I have response like encrypt data and it should decrypt before checking case in Wiremock after that send response as encrypt data

Comment: Like this 

{'data': 'encrypt Data'} } -- decrypt---> {'petId':123}  -- checking dat in Wiremock --> {'responseCode':'success'} ---encrypt----> {'data' : ' encrypt response' } 
If not, I will reseach other program to do this TT